# javascript: Comparing dates in different timezones

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

My requirement is to do client side validation against a Date. The date will turn off functionality and will use an Eastern Timezone value. Daylight savings is not an issue here.

I have been attempting to use a Javascript Date as a constant and I've just discovered that the millisecond value of a Date will be different in different timezones.

```
new Date(2015, 2, 1, 4 , 59, 59).getTime()
1425207599000 --> result in Central
1425203999000 --> result in Eastern
```

Date has no setTimezoneOffset and seems like overriding getTimezoneOffset() isn't helpful either.

My approach is to use the long value of the date in EST timezone (1425203999000 ) as a constant and do a `date1.getTime() > 1425203999000`

Does this sound reasonable? Any considerations I've missed?

Comment: look into using UTC date.

Comment: yes, I've decided to use Date.UTC(yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm,ss).  I'm a little surprised you can't pass a   Date object in... but my biggest surprise is that new Date.getTime() doesn't seem to factor in timezone offset.

Comment: you are working with server time vs user time, have to be careful how you plan strategy for it

Answer (score 2):

This sounds completely reasonable, and it's how I roll.  The long value of the date is not dependent on timezone.  It measures milliseconds since some standard time in the 70's.

Comment: Since 01-01-1970T00:00:00.000Z UTC to be precise